# Copying a suspended VM

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, suspend

I have 2 VMs (Ubuntu and Windows) running on my desktop with VMWare Workstation. I regularly suspend them to preserve the OS state.

Is it possible to copy these VMs to another machine with VMWare Workstation or Player, and run them without errors?

Comment: You are not going to be able to properly clarify be them in a suspended state

Answer (score 0):

### Is it possible to resume a suspended VM on a different host?

Yes, of course.  That is basically how [vMotion](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/vmotion.html) works.

### Is it *guaranteed* to be able to resume a suspended VM on a different host without error?

If you have the right conditions, there should be no errors.  If you don't however, then no, you might get errors when trying to resume the VM.  Some errors might be mostly innocuous (e.g. if the VM wants to connect to the host sound card, but the new host doesn't have one).  Some might prevent the VM from resuming (e.g. host CPU differences).